# Creating a Data Frame from Multiple Files That Contains a Column Specifying File Origin Using a For Loop

Tags: r, loops, vector, append, organization

I have four CSV files. Each of those files are identical in structure and contain 21 columns (the first being the time point) and the next 20 are different kinds of data points. Each file has a different number of rows, however.

I wish to create a data frame for each of the 20 columns (all of the columns besides the first, which is time). This data frame would contain two columns (1: my data from a specific column (i.e. column number 3) from all four CSV files and 2: the level (1 for data points acquired from CSV file 1, 2 for CSV file 2, 3 for CSV file 3, and 4 for CSV file 4).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
J

Since I want to complete this task 20 times, I thought it would be wise to use a for loop. Below is my code. I get the same error every time I run the code: "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length".

```
# Vectors contains the vectors that will hold the data specific to each column from all four CSV files
# Doc1, Doc2, Doc3, and Doc4 are data frames that contain each of the columns (besides the first one (time)) of the original CSV files. In this case, the first column in any of these files corresponds to the second column in the original CSV file. 

Vectors = c(Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15, Col16, Col17, Col18, Col19, Col20, Col21)

for (value in c(1:20)) {
  Levels = c() # levels signifies the document of origin per data point (i.e. 1 for CSV file 1, 2 for CSV file 2, etc.)
  Vectors[value] = c(Doc1[,value])
  Vectors[value] = append(Vectors[value], Doc2[,value])
  Vectors[value] = append(Vectors[value], Doc3[,value])
  Vectors[value] = append(Vectors[value], Doc4[,value])
  Levels = c(rep(1, length(Doc1[,value]))
  Levels = append(Levels, rep(2, length(Doc2[,value])))
  Levels = append(Levels, rep(3, length(Doc3[,value])))
  Levels = append(Levels, rep(4, length(Doc4[,value])))
  Vectors[value] = data.frame(Vectors[value], Levels)
}
```

I expected the for loop to run and assign values to each of the vectors in Vectors. Again, the values assigned to those vectors would be the data stored in a specific number column in each of the CSV files (doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4). I then expected the for loop to generate levels corresponding to each of the data points. Then, I expected the for loop to join these two as a data frame, which would be named Col2, Col3, or etc., depending on how many times the for loop has run.

Instead, I would get the following warning message: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length.

Again, thanks in advance for any and all help. I am new to R and I really appreciate any advice anyone has to offer.

Answer (score 0):

As nicely and carefully you may think you have asked this question, A picture (or data!) is worth a thousand words. May I suggest you boil down your issue to the smallest possible dataset, AND may I even suggest developing pseudo-code for you issue and showing that.